# table *** has no column named ***

Tags: android, database, eclipse

Hello Guys ive got a DB and created a new Edit Text field to save a new column im my database called COLUMN_AUSWIRKUNGEN ...if i go to my app on my device, enter a text and click on confirm button ,the error log give me this :

```
07-31 16:19:23.368: E/SQLiteLog(10039): (1) table todo has no column named auswirkungen
07-31 16:19:23.378: E/SQLiteDatabase(10039): Error inserting summary=texthere category=Sehr Wichtig (Folgenschwer bei Versagen) description=text here too auswirkungen=here is the column that dont work
07-31 16:19:23.378: E/SQLiteDatabase(10039): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table todo has no column named auswirkungen (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO todo(summary,category,description,auswirkungen) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
07-31 16:19:23.378: E/SQLiteDatabase(10039):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
07-31 16:19:23.378: E/SQLiteDatabase(10039):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:923)
07-31 16:19:23.378: E/SQLiteDatabase(10039):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:534)
07-31 16:19:23.378: E/SQLiteDatabase(10039):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
07-31 16:19:23.378: E/SQLiteDatabase(10039):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
07-31 16:19:23.378: E/SQLiteDatabase(10039):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
07-31 16:19:23.378: E/SQLiteDatabase(10039):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1523)
07-31 16:19:23.378: E/SQLiteDatabase(10039):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1395)
07-31 16:19:23.378: E/SQLiteDatabase(10039):    at de.vogella.android.todos.contentprovider.MyTodoContentProvider.insert(MyTodoContentProvider.java:86)
07-31 16:19:23.378: E/SQLiteDatabase(10039):    at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.insert(ContentProvider.java:232)
07-31 16:19:23.378: E/SQLiteDatabase(10039):    at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1213)
07-31 16:19:23.378: E/SQLiteDatabase(10039):    at de.vogella.android.todos.TodoDetailActivity.saveState(TodoDetailActivity.java:115)
07-31 16:19:23.378: E/SQLiteDatabase(10039):    at de.vogella.android.todos.TodoDetailActivity.onPause(TodoDetailActivity.java:95)
07-31 16:19:23.378: E/SQLiteDatabase(10039):    at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:5442)
07-31 16:19:23.378: E/SQLiteDatabase(10039):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1356)
07-31 16:19:23.378: E/SQLiteDatabase(10039):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
07-31 16:19:23.378: E/SQLiteDatabase(10039):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3570)
07-31 16:19:23.378: E/SQLiteDatabase(10039):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3547)
07-31 16:19:23.378: E/SQLiteDatabase(10039):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:156)
07-31 16:19:23.378: E/SQLiteDatabase(10039):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1372)
07-31 16:19:23.378: E/SQLiteDatabase(10039):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-31 16:19:23.378: E/SQLiteDatabase(10039):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
07-31 16:19:23.378: E/SQLiteDatabase(10039):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
07-31 16:19:23.378: E/SQLiteDatabase(10039):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-31 16:19:23.378: E/SQLiteDatabase(10039):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-31 16:19:23.378: E/SQLiteDatabase(10039):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:852)
07-31 16:19:23.378: E/SQLiteDatabase(10039):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:668)
```

### 07-31 16:19:23.378: E/SQLiteDatabase(10039):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

**here is my db**

```
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;

public class TodoTable {

    // Database table
    public static final String TABLE_TODO = "todo";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_CATEGORY = "category";
    public static final String COLUMN_SUMMARY = "summary";
    public static final String COLUMN_DESCRIPTION = "description";
    public static final String COLUMN_AUSWIRKUNGEN = "auswirkungen";
    // Database creation SQL statement
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " + TABLE_TODO
            + "(" + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + ""
            + COLUMN_CATEGORY + " text not null, " + COLUMN_SUMMARY
            + " text not null," + COLUMN_DESCRIPTION + " text not null" 
            + COLUMN_AUSWIRKUNGEN+ " text not null"
            +
            ");";

    public static void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    public static void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion,
            int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TodoTable.class.getName(), "Upgrading database from version "
                + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion
                + ", which will destroy all old data");
        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_TODO);
        onCreate(database);
    }
}
```

**the content provider**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.UriMatcher;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import de.vogella.android.todos.database.TodoDatabaseHelper;
import de.vogella.android.todos.database.TodoTable;

public class MyTodoContentProvider extends ContentProvider {
    // database
    private TodoDatabaseHelper database;
    // Used for the UriMacher
    private static final int TODOS = 10;
    private static final int TODO_ID = 20;
    private static final String AUTHORITY = "de.vogella.android.todos.contentprovider";
    private static final String BASE_PATH = "todos";
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY
            + "/" + BASE_PATH);
    public static final String CONTENT_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_DIR_BASE_TYPE
            + "/todos";
    public static final String CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_ITEM_BASE_TYPE
            + "/todo";
    private static final UriMatcher sURIMatcher = new UriMatcher(
            UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    static {
        sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, BASE_PATH, TODOS);
        sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, BASE_PATH + "/#", TODO_ID);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        database = new TodoDatabaseHelper(getContext());
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        // Uisng SQLiteQueryBuilder instead of query() method
        SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        // Check if the caller has requested a column which does not exists
        checkColumns(projection);
        // Set the table
        queryBuilder.setTables(TodoTable.TABLE_TODO);
        int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
        switch (uriType) {
        case TODOS:
            break;
        case TODO_ID:
            // Adding the ID to the original query
            queryBuilder.appendWhere(TodoTable.COLUMN_ID + "="
                    + uri.getLastPathSegment());
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
        }
        SQLiteDatabase db = database.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = queryBuilder.query(db, projection, selection,
                selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
        // Make sure that potential listeners are getting notified
        cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
        return cursor;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
        SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = database.getWritableDatabase();
        int rowsDeleted = 0;
        long id = 0;
        switch (uriType) {
        case TODOS:
            id = sqlDB.insert(TodoTable.TABLE_TODO, null, values);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
        }
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        return Uri.parse(BASE_PATH + "/" + id);
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
        SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = database.getWritableDatabase();
        int rowsDeleted = 0;
        switch (uriType) {
        case TODOS:
            rowsDeleted = sqlDB.delete(TodoTable.TABLE_TODO, selection,
                    selectionArgs);
            break;
        case TODO_ID:
            String id = uri.getLastPathSegment();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(selection)) {
                rowsDeleted = sqlDB.delete(TodoTable.TABLE_TODO,
                        TodoTable.COLUMN_ID + "=" + id, null);
            } else {
                rowsDeleted = sqlDB.delete(TodoTable.TABLE_TODO,
                        TodoTable.COLUMN_ID + "=" + id + " and " + selection,
                        selectionArgs);
            }
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
        }
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        return rowsDeleted;
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs) {
        int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
        SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = database.getWritableDatabase();
        int rowsUpdated = 0;
        switch (uriType) {
        case TODOS:
            rowsUpdated = sqlDB.update(TodoTable.TABLE_TODO, values, selection,
                    selectionArgs);
            break;
        case TODO_ID:
            String id = uri.getLastPathSegment();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(selection)) {
                rowsUpdated = sqlDB.update(TodoTable.TABLE_TODO, values,
                        TodoTable.COLUMN_ID + "=" + id, null);
            } else {
                rowsUpdated = sqlDB.update(TodoTable.TABLE_TODO, values,
                        TodoTable.COLUMN_ID + "=" + id + " and " + selection,
                        selectionArgs);
            }
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
        }
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        return rowsUpdated;
    }

    private void checkColumns(String[] projection) {
        String[] available = { TodoTable.COLUMN_CATEGORY,
                TodoTable.COLUMN_SUMMARY, TodoTable.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION,
                TodoTable.COLUMN_ID ,TodoTable.COLUMN_AUSWIRKUNGEN};
        if (projection != null) {
            HashSet<String> requestedColumns = new HashSet<String>(
                    Arrays.asList(projection));
            HashSet<String> availableColumns = new HashSet<String>(
                    Arrays.asList(available));
            // Check if all columns which are requested are available
            if (!availableColumns.containsAll(requestedColumns)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        "Unknown columns in projection");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**After reinstalling app on my phone i get this error **

```
07-31 20:23:29.257: W/asset(2255): Copying FileAsset 0x780f87a8 (zip:/data/app/de.vogella.android.todos-2.apk:/resources.arsc) to buffer size 3392 to make it aligned.
07-31 20:23:29.337: E/SQLiteLog(2255): (1) near "nullauswirkungen": syntax error
07-31 20:23:29.337: W/dalvikvm(2255): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41b2ee18)
07-31 20:23:29.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2255): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
07-31 20:23:29.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2255): Process: de.vogella.android.todos, PID: 2255
07-31 20:23:29.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2255): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-31 20:23:29.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2255):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
07-31 20:23:29.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2255):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
07-31 20:23:29.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2255):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
07-31 20:23:29.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2255):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
07-31 20:23:29.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2255):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
07-31 20:23:29.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2255):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
07-31 20:23:29.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2255):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
07-31 20:23:29.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2255): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "nullauswirkungen": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: create table todo(_id integer primary key autoincrement, category text not null, summary text not null,description text not nullauswirkungen text not null);
07-31 20:23:29.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2255):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
07-31 20:23:29.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2255):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:923)
07-31 20:23:29.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2255):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:534)
07-31 20:23:29.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2255):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
07-31 20:23:29.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2255):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
07-31 20:23:29.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2255):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
07-31 20:23:29.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2255):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1728)
07-31 20:23:29.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2255):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1659)
07-31 20:23:29.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2255):     at de.vogella.android.todos.database.TodoTable.onCreate(TodoTable.java:23)
07-31 20:23:29.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2255):     at de.vogella.android.todos.database.TodoDatabaseHelper.onCreate(TodoDatabaseHelper.java:18)
07-31 20:23:29.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2255):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
07-31 20:23:29.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2255):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
07-31 20:23:29.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2255):     at de.vogella.android.todos.contentprovider.MyTodoContentProvider.query(MyTodoContentProvider.java:65)
07-31 20:23:29.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2255):     at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:869)
07-31 20:23:29.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2255):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:212)
07-31 20:23:29.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2255):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:476)
07-31 20:23:29.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2255):     at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:65)
07-31 20:23:29.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2255):     at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:43)
07-31 20:23:29.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2255):     at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:312)
07-31 20:23:29.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2255):     at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:69)
07-31 20:23:29.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2255):     at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:57)
07-31 20:23:29.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2255):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
07-31 20:23:29.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2255):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-31 20:23:29.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2255):     ... 3 more
07-31 20:23:29.367: I/Adreno-EGL(2255): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:385>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_KK_3.5_RB1.04.04.02.006.066_msm8974_refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_KK_3.5_RB1.04.04.02.006.066__release_AU ()
07-31 20:23:29.367: I/Adreno-EGL(2255): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.06
07-31 20:23:29.367: I/Adreno-EGL(2255): Build Date: 02/06/14 Thu
07-31 20:23:29.367: I/Adreno-EGL(2255): Local Branch: 
07-31 20:23:29.367: I/Adreno-EGL(2255): Remote Branch: refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_KK_3.5_RB1.04.04.02.006.066
07-31 20:23:29.367: I/Adreno-EGL(2255): Local Patches: NONE
07-31 20:23:29.367: I/Adreno-EGL(2255): Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
```

Comment: did you update your database version? uninstalling/reinstalling the app will fix the problem

Comment: thx for this help, but now when i start the app it quit immediately the application. i edit the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
" text not null" 
        + COLUMN_AUSWIRKUNGEN+
```

You can see that you miss a comma after null. It should be:

```
" text not null, " 
        + COLUMN_AUSWIRKUNGEN+
```

Otherwise the table won't be created.

By the way, this `+ ""` is **completely useless** and introduces some extra work (one more string concatenation)

Comment: Often, bugs have a special ability to hide in the smallest places!